# Pagespeedmodule - Build a ressources server

Tags: nginx, pagespeed

I use Nginx and I have installed Google PageSpeedModule on one of my domain. This module is really usefull, and easy to use. All CSS and JS are minified, my images are compressed... it has reduced the weight of 500 kb of my pages.

My question is, can I use this module to deliver only ressources ? I create a kind of CDN, containing all my CSS, images, JS... But, I installed Nginx + pagespeedmodule and the module is not working for one image only for example. But it works with an HTML page and compress the images in this page, but can it work with a direct access image ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`InPlaceResourceOptimization`](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#ipro) to optimize images even if they are not optimized in HTML (Note: That doc says that this is an Apache-only feature, but that's out of date, it works in the latest Nginx as well.). Add this command to your config:

```
pagespeed InPlaceResourceOptimization on;
```

Note that the default way that ngx_pagespeed works is by rewriting resources found in HTML. That is the most efficient way to run it. If you only use `InPlaceResourceOptimization` you will not get some advantages like cache extension and image resizing. However this is a convenient feature if you cannot optimize resources in HTML.

Comment: It works ! Thanks ! My point was to obtain image compression "on the fly". And it works on Nginx 1.4.4.